# Dynamically change onClick in android based on xml tags

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So, I've got my app that I want to be easily changeable.  As in, I want to be able to just make xml files and not have to alter the java at all, customized for each client.  This is for a kiosk-like software where there isn't a whole lot of need for extra functionality, just information.

I have it set up with fragments so that it will replace the fragment on a button click, like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    layoutId = R.layout.fragment_ad;

    fragment.setLayoutId(layoutId);

    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.top_main, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

layoutId is a variable that I made in the MainFragment class that lets it know what xml file to go to when it calls transaction.replace().

Here is a snippet from the xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_weight="2.75"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:tag="R.layout/fragment_ad"
    / >
```

Now what I would like to do is, instead of setting layoutId to R.layout.fragment_ad, I'd like to replace it with what v.getTag() is pointing to.  However, v.getTag() is an object that can be converted into a string, or an int, or a few other things, but cannot be used to get layout information from R.

Is there a way I can use the contents of android:tag and have it get the layout id that the tag's text is pointing to?  I'm not stubborn about using the tag, though, so if anyone comes up with a better solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String buttonTag = button.getTag().toString();
layoutId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(buttonTag, "layout", app_package_name);
```

Where `this` represents the Acivity. And in xml:

```
android:tag="fragment_ad"
```

But this way of obtaining identifiers is very slow.